# how to get all the fields in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to get all the fields from the table which i select in the query even if the fields contains no value(the value null or empty). the following is the query i have written.

```
SELECT (
           SELECT T1.[CarrierCode_Destination] AS '@CarrierCode_Destination',
                  T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address] AS 
                  '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address',
                  T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address1] AS 
                  '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address1',
                  T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address2] AS 
                  '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address2',
                  T1.[CIMtrek_RegContact] AS '@CIMtrek_RegContact',
                  T1.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact] AS '@CIMtrek_CarrierContact',
                  [T1].[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts] AS 
                  '@CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts'
           FROM   (
                      SELECT CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName] 
                             CarrierCode_Destination,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd] 
                             CarrierCode_Destination_Address,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_1] 
                             CarrierCode_Destination_Address1,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_2] 
                             CarrierCode_Destination_Address2,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_RegContact] CIMtrek_RegContact,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact] CIMtrek_CarrierContact,
                             CD.[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts] 
                             CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts
                      FROM   CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse CD
                      WHERE  LEN(
                                 LTRIM(
                                     RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName])), ''))
                                 )
                             ) != 0
                  ) AS T1 
                  FOR XML PATH('Record'),
                  TYPE
       ) FOR XML PATH('CarrierCode_Destination'),
       TYPE
```

the results i get is

```
<CarrierCode_Destination>
  <Record CarrierCode_Destination="8S - San Fran" CarrierCode_Destination_Address="SAN FRANCISCO  -  Redistribution" CarrierCode_Destination_Address1="4025 Whipple Road, " CarrierCode_Destination_Address2="Union City CA  94587" CIMtrek_RegContact="RDC San Francisco" />
  <Record CarrierCode_Destination="8G - St Louis" CarrierCode_Destination_Address="ST. LOUIS  -  Redistribution" CarrierCode_Destination_Address1="126 Enterprise  Drive, " CarrierCode_Destination_Address2="Wentzville MO  63385" CIMtrek_RegContact="RDC St Louis" />
  <Record CarrierCode_Destination="V8     PHO/CYPR/CUST/TL  " />
</CarrierCode_Destination>
```

but i want all the fields which are selected in the query. If you see the result it gives me the fields which are having value and omits the fields which don't have values.

how to do this, Please help.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402703/t-sql-2005-passing-null-values-through-xml-datatype ?

Comment: There is an [`XSINIL` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx), but it can only be specified with `ELEMENTS`, which I think would change the shape of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `isnull()` statements for each column you are selecting and convert null values to empty strings it should force the attributes to be generated for all columns. You may or may not also need to add `rtrim()` statements like I show below depending on if you have a datatype that is going to return a fixed size string:

```
SELECT (
       SELECT rtrim(isnull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination],'')) AS '@CarrierCode_Destination',
              rtrim(isnull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address1],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address1',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address2],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address2',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CIMtrek_RegContact],'')) AS '@CIMtrek_RegContact',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact],'')) AS '@CIMtrek_CarrierContact',
              rtrim(IsNull([T1].[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts],'')) AS 
              '@CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts'
       FROM   (
                  SELECT CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName] 
                         CarrierCode_Destination,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd] 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_1] 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address1,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_2] 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address2,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_RegContact] CIMtrek_RegContact,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact] CIMtrek_CarrierContact,
                         CD.[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts] 
                         CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts
                  FROM   CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse CD
                  WHERE  LEN(
                             LTRIM(
                                 RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName])), ''))
                             )
                         ) != 0
              ) AS T1 
              FOR XML PATH('Record'),
              TYPE
   ) FOR XML PATH('CarrierCode_Destination'),
   TYPE
```

That worked for me when I tested it out but if you are also having issues with empty values not generating attributes  you can first force all the empty values to be returned as `NULL` from the select against your original data table using `NULLIF()`

```
SELECT (
       SELECT rtrim(isnull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination],'')) AS '@CarrierCode_Destination',
              rtrim(isnull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address1],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address1',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CarrierCode_Destination_Address2],'')) AS 
              '@CarrierCode_Destination_Address2',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CIMtrek_RegContact],'')) AS '@CIMtrek_RegContact',
              rtrim(IsNull(T1.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact],'')) AS '@CIMtrek_CarrierContact',
              rtrim(IsNull([T1].[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts],'')) AS 
              '@CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts'
       FROM   (
                  SELECT NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName],'') 
                         CarrierCode_Destination,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd],'') 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_1],'') 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address1,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationAdd_2],'') 
                         CarrierCode_Destination_Address2,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_RegContact],'') CIMtrek_RegContact,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_CarrierContact],'') CIMtrek_CarrierContact,
                         NullIF(CD.[CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts],'') 
                         CIMtrek_AdditionalContacts
                  FROM   CIMtrek_SystemTable_DatawareHouse CD
                  WHERE  LEN(
                             LTRIM(
                                 RTRIM(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(CD.[CIMtrek_DestinationName])), ''))
                             )
                         ) != 0
              ) AS T1 
              FOR XML PATH('Record'),
              TYPE
   ) FOR XML PATH('CarrierCode_Destination'),
   TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  FIELD_NAME = "CRITERIA"
```

Comment: Criteria oops sorry for the typo